# when press it get table row info to display with image

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

when I click the button it will open a pop-up screen with the image ID,image file name , image text output and date with image with in the pop up screen for each rows.I provided a screenshot with the table layout and my code. I’m having trouble when I click on the button it will not show me the information for each row.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search").keyup(function() {
    _this = this;
    $.each($("#article_table tbody tr"), function() {
      if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) === -1)
        $(this).hide();
      else
        $(this).show();
    });
  });

  $.getJSON("../Image_to_text_with_Tesseract/images_content_json.json", function(data) {
    console.log(data) //just to log in console as well
    var article_data = '';

    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
      article_data += '<tr>';
      article_data += '<td>' + value.Image_id + '</td>';
      article_data += '<td>' + value.image_file_name + '</td>';
      article_data += '<td>' + value.Image_Text_output + '</td>';
      article_data += '<td>' + value.date + '</td>';
      article_data += '<td><img src="' + value.image_file_name + '"></td>';
      article_data += '<td><button  type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="Show"  >' + value.button + '</button></td>';
      article_data += '</tr>';
    });

    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
      article_data += '<h4>' + value.Image_id + '</h4>';
    });

    $('#article_table').append(article_data);
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border: 2px solid #666;
  width: 10%;
}

th {
  background: #f8f8f8;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 2px;
}

td {
  width: 1%;
}

img {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />

<script type="text/javascript" src='https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="../webDatabase/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" class="form-control pull-center" id="search" placeholder="Type to search table...">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="one_article" style="">
      <table id="article_table" class="table table-bordered ">
        <td>Image_id</td>
        <td>image_file_name</td>
        <td>Image_Text_output</td>
        <td>date</td>
        <td>Show_image</td>
        <td>View</td>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">{{Image_id}}</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[image: when you press button this will popup]

Comment: I was wondering if you could  fix it. I am not sure what to change or fix

Comment: Doing it for you would be a disservice. This is stuff you should learn. Click the 'edited yesterday' link above to see the edit history. Find the line for the Bootstrap 3.3.7 script and put it in where the version 3.0.3 script is in your snippet now. Remove the jQuery script and use the button in the snippet editor to add the latest jQuery. If you don't understand what we're doing here, search "what is a cdn" and "bootstrap cdn" and "jquery cdn".

Comment: Then look at the specs for [an HTML table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) and add the missing row element I mentioned early on to make that markup valid. Your script simply won't work without it because it _references_ the row element. Then let's see where we're at.